# How to write .htaccess dynamically?

Tags: theme-development, htaccess, actions

I am trying to set permalink structure on theme activation. The following function included in function.php of theme.

```
// Executes function on theme activation
function myactivationfunction() {

    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure( '/%category%/%postname%/' );
    // register taxonomies/post types here
    flush_rewrite_rules();

}
add_action("after_switch_theme", "myactivationfunction", 10 ,  2);
```

This code works correctly but value not writing into .htaccess or .htaccess not creating. How can i write .htaccess file dynamically?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `flush_rewrite_rules()` restores the .htaccess rules automatically. These are the same for almost all rules, so don’t expect to see any changes. Look at the last modified time to see if the file was updated.

Comment: If i delete .htaccess file before activating theme and .htaccess not creating after activation of theme.

Comment: the .htaccess is creating when i access the permalink options under settings of wordpress dashboard.

Comment: why do you want to change .htaccess? for your permalink structure setting? If so, it's no need to deal with .htaccess.  rewrite rules of permalink structures are stored in database. you just need to make sure any kind of url will be pointing to index.php in htaccess.

Comment: @Jesse Thanks for your reply. Probably there should be a 404 error while moving to inner pages of the site if the permalink is `'/%category%/%postname%/'`. To avoid this need to update .htaccess.

Comment: I don't understand why it would be needed to change the `.htaccess` file dynamically. This question lacks a lot of info and sounds more like a XY problem.

Comment: @kaiser My need is, just want to set permalink on theme activation. When i change permalink to "/%category%/%postname%/" on theme activation, i could not navigate category page and single page of post in browser. it only displaying 404 page when i move to inner pages on browser. The reason is that the .htaccess is not updated. I don't know how to update .htaccess on theme activation.